# Как проверить загружена ли картинка если неизвестно расширение

Tags: javascript

При загрузке картинки для страницы сайта на сервер картинка получает имя в соответствии с относительным путем страницы с заменой слешей на дефисы + добавляется индекс. Например если страница имеет путь `/category/product` то первая загруженная для нее картинка получит имя **category-product-1.png** (если например расширение png). Соответственно при загрузке второй картинки она получит имя **category-product-2.png** и т.д.

Нужно проверить на чистом Javascript последнюю загруженную картинку для текущей страницы т.е. с самым большим индексом. При этом не зная с каким именно расширением была загружена картинка.

Пока есть вот это:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var fullRelativePath = window.location.pathname.substring(1);
var fullRelativePath = fullRelativePath.replace('/','-');
var img = new Image();
for(i = 1; i <= 100; i++) { // ограничимся сотней картинок для страницы
    img.src = '/images/'+fullRelativePath+i+'.png'; // хотя на самом деле расширение неизвестно (jpg|png|gif)
    img.addEventListener('load', function(){
        console.log('Uploaded');
    });
    img.addEventListener('error', function(){
        return false;
    });
}
</script>
```

В данном случае не знаю как решить две проблемы:

**1.** Консоль не выдает `Uploaded` если загружена хоть одна картинка для страницы, только если загружена картинка с максимальным индексом

**2.** Не знаю как проверять не только .png, а все три возможные расширения: `jpg|png|gif` (jpEg не нужно) если неизвестно с каким расширением загружена картинка

Нужно проверять именно через `onload` сразу после загрузки, а не через `if(img.height > 0)` поскольку второй вариант проверяет лишь картинку, которая уже кешировалась. Проверять нужно именно ЗАГРУЖЕННЫЕ в папку `/images`, а не вставленные на саму страницу, на странице картинки пока нету.

И прошу не ставить флаг "дубликат", поскольку вопросы о том как просто проверить загружена ли картинка это не мой вопрос, мой специфический

---

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ #1**

Придумал такой костыль:

```
var images = [];
for(i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    images.push('-'+i+'.jpg');
    images.push('-'+i+'.png');
    images.push('-'+i+'.gif');
}

var fullRelativePath = window.location.pathname.substring(1);
var fullRelativePath = fullRelativePath.replace('/','-');
var img = new Image();
for(var i = 1; i < images.length; i++) {
    img.src = '/images/'+fullRelativePath+images[i];
    img.addEventListener('load', function(){
        console.log('Uploaded');
    });
    img.addEventListener('error', function(){
        return false;
    });
}
```

Но может как то попроще? И остается проблема #1

---

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ #2**

Если все картинки одного расширения тогда можно вот так:

```
function checkTheNext(n) {
    var fullRelativePath = window.location.pathname.substring(1);
    var fullRelativePath = fullRelativePath.replace('/','-');
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = '/images/'+fullRelativePath+'-'+n+'.jpg';
    img.addEventListener('load', function(){
        checkTheNext(n+1); // если картинка загружена, то проверяем следующую
    });
    img.addEventListener('error', function(){
        console.log(n-1); // индекс последней загруженной картинки
        return false;
    });
}
checkTheNext(n = 1);
```

Но теперь всё наоборот: решена проблема #1, но вернулась проблема #2.

Comment: У Вас цикл проходит быстрее, чем загрузится хоть одна картинка. Потому и есть проблема #1

Answer (score 1):

Ты на правильном пути. Но попробуй вместо new Image с последующим присвоением src, выбрать все картинки на странице или в нужном контейнере, пробежаться по ним циклом, и навешать события.

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll("img");
for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
{
   images[i].addEventListener("load", () => console.log("Loaded"));
}
```

Comment: Не, нужно проверять картинки загруженные в папку /images, а не на странице, на странице их пока нету

Comment: Ничего не мешает проверить images[i].src на соответствие желаемому пути

Comment: `document.querySelector("img")` берет лишь картинки `<img/>` со страницы, а не файлы картинок, загруженные в папку на сервере

Comment: Из браузера никак не узнать какие там файлы в папке на сервере. Либо надо иметь список файлов, либо брать их со страницы. document.querySelectorAll позволяет выбрать все картинки, которые есть на странице, и ты можешь с ними что-то сделать, например дождаться загрузки всех. Если у тебя есть какой-то список файлов, то ты их можешь загрузить использовав new Image(). И так-же дождаться их загрузки. Отличие лишь в том, как ты получаешь список элементов.